# Moved a directory to an unknown .../ place (three dots)

Tags: files, mv

I came across this weird situation when I accidentally moved one of my directory to an unknown place I am unable to find.

What I did was executed this command -

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/cake$ mv cakephp/ .../
```

It did executed without any error, and now I am not able to locate my directory.

I googled this issue but I am not getting any help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Another case of Linux assuming that you know what you're doing. And since it starts with a dot, it's hidden by default.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You renamed the directory `cakephp` in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/cake` to `...`. Your command was perfectly valid, therefore it did not produce an error.

You should be able to find the directory at `/opt/lampp/htdocs/cake/...`. Note that files/folder starting with a dot are hidden (hence you need to use, e.g., `ls -a /opt/lampp/htdocs/cake` to see it).

Comment: Thanks for reply... I figured it out when i searched it with `triple dot ubuntu` in google.

Comment: Although, to be a bit pedantic, you shouldn't have had permission to rename a directory under `/opt` without `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks @Jos Its my personal development machine so I have given my `htdocs` a `777`

Comment: @easycoder that gives anyone rights to create a file, I'd restore it to `755` and do `chown -R $USER:$USER`

Comment: You are right @Jos. I will change that on priority... thanks